# Calling JavaScript from Kotlin

Tags: javascript, react-native, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I have ReactNative project and I'm trying to call simple JS function from Kotlin (calling Kotlin from JS works fine). My project directory looks like this:
[image]

"shared" module is compiled as commonjs module.
In Main.kt I have (shortened):

```
external fun myFun()
```

In App.js I have (shortened):

```
import * as shared from './shared/build/classes/kotlin/main/shared.js'
export function myFun(){
    console.log("Hello")
}
```

So I'm trying to call myFun() from Kotlin to get console log in JS. But I get exception:

```
myFun is not defined
```

I was looking to this docs:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html#applying-jsmodule-to-packages
But I not sure how to use those annotations (if they are needed?).
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should annotate your kotlin declaration with

```
@JsModule("<module_name>") // seems like it is App
external fun myFun()
```

and setup module kind to `umd` in gradle sript like this

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "umd"
```